# Struggling with some more advanced authorizations using CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, rails-admin

Brand new to both Ruby and Rails here, and I just got started on my first project. Went through the new tutorial on Lynda first, then started a new project where I'm so far using RailsAdmin, CanCan and Devise.

Trying to do some more advanced authorization with CanCan, and I'm struggling a bit figuring out how to do this. For a normal user I'm now doing:

```
can :access, :rails_admin
can :dashboard
can :read, [Company, ProductCategory]
can [:read, :update], User, :id => user.id
can :manage, [Product, Catalog], :company_id => user.company.id
can :manage, [Image, Video, Document, Link]
cannot :export, :all
```

Which is working great, but I'm struggling a bit with images, videos, documents and links. These all belong_to a Product or a Catalog, and doing it the way I'm doing it above gives the user access to any file. So ideally I would want something like:

```
can :manage, [Image, Video, Document, Link], :product.company_id => user.company.id
```

But obviously I can't do that since there is no :product, but just the :product_id of the product the file belongs to. So how would I access the company id of the product referred to by the :product_id on the files?

In addition to that a company can be a subcompany of another company (which can be a subcompany of another company etc etc). So how would I do something like:

```
can :manage [Product, Catalog], [:company_id, :company.company.id, :company.company.company.id (etc)] => user.company.id
```

Basically a user should be able to manage products and catalogs that belong to their company, or that belong to any subcompany of their company.

---

**EDITED** for clarity and simplification

Company1 has sub-company Company2, Company2 has sub-company Company3 and Company3 has sub-company Company4.

User belongs to Company2 (not Company1).

User should then manage all Companies starting at Company2, meaning it should be able to manage Company2, Company3 and Company4, but not Company1.

So I tried adding:

```
can :manage, Company, :company_id => user.company.id
can :manage, Company, :company => { :company_id => user.company.id }
can :manage, Company, :company => { :company => { :company_id => user.company.id } }
```

So the 2 first lines here seem to work, and I can see both Company2 and Company3. But Company4 - which is supposed to be handled by the third line - does not seem to show in the listing nor can it be managed by this user.

So… Why isn't that line working? And how can I get this all on one line and handled unlimited levels of companies instead of adding one line for each new level I add?

Answer (score 1):

**First part:**

Assumptions:

- User belongs to Company
- Product belongs to Company
- Image belongs to Product
- Document belongs to Catalog

These all permissions are affordable, by the third parameter of `can` method, e.g:

```
can :manage, Image, :product => { :company => user.company_id  }
```

If company has many catalogs:

```
can :manage, Document, :catalog => { :company => user.company_id  }
```

or if product has many catalogs:

```
can :manage, Document, :catalog => { :product => { :company => user.company_id  } }
```

**Second part:**

Assumptions:

- Company model has `company_id` to meet the requirement "Company has many Companies has many Companies etc"

So that, this if the first part (User can manage Companies):

```
can :manage, [Product, Catalog], :company_id => user.company_id
```

and that's all. It is not important here how nested is the companies tree, the significant part is user always belongs to an Company and it doesn't matter if it's Company or Subcompany of Company.

Comment: That was very helpful, but I'm still struggling a bit (and I might have not explained my model structure very well for the second problem).

Company1 has sub-company Company2, Company2 has sub-company Company3 and Company3 has sub-company Company4.

Product1 belongs to Company1, Product2 belongs to Company2 etc.

Comment: Well, but still, it's just Company model with a few levels of nested associations, right? However, if you're saying about the case that if user can manage resources of Company1 then he also can manage Company2..4 - it would need another another approach then

Comment: Any idea why line 1 and 2 works, but not line 3? And I presume from your comment it's not possible to do this on a single line with CanCan?

Comment: Company4 isn't visible/manageable by the user. 

It almost seems like it can only go one level down. Like I can query for company.company, but not company.company.company.

Comment: You can nest company association as many times as you like. `Company.first.company.company.company` is still fine. It's just a matter of model associations.

Comment: Then I'm at a loss as to why line 1 and 2 works, but not line 3.

Comment: I haven't nested and yet, tested such association tree. Such hash `:catalog => { :product => { :company => user.company_id  } }` is just a representation of `INNER JOIN` to the Company model itself. You can see that in your server logs (how cancan queries data to check for given permission).

Comment: There's another solution for that. I mean you can use (block)[https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks] for given permission and then check for company associations in such manner: `company.try(:company).try(:company).present?`. However, it would be really inefficient since it seeds three additional queries to get the result.